# JS detect the width of the screen, running a different JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write two js code. I want first detect the width of the screen, then run a different JS files. How to write correctly?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ((screen.width>=1024) && (screen.height>=768)) 
{ 
    $("link[text/javascript]:not(:first)").attr({src : "1024.js"}); 
} 
else 
{ 
    $("link[text/javascript]:not(:first)").attr({src : "768.js"}); 
} 
});
<script src="1024.js"></script>
<script src="768.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ((screen.width>=1024) && (screen.height>=768)) 
{ 
    $.getScript("1024.js",function({}));
} 
else 
{ 
    $.getScript("768.js",function({}));
} 
});
```